# Problems with the TextView position

Tags: android, android-studio

I need to avoid textview touching each other, I tried many ways but I cant make it work.... What I should do? Thanks! Please view my screenshot

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqzVd.png)

> ```
> <RelativeLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
>     android:background="#ffffff"
>     android:padding="15dp">
>
>     <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/imageView"
>         android:layout_width="65dp"
>         android:layout_height="65dp"
>         android:layout_weight="0.11" />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/tvnombre"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>         android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
>         android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvultvalor"
>         android:paddingLeft="15dp"
>         android:textColor="#333"
>         android:textSize="16dp"
>         android:layout_weight="1"
>         android:textStyle="bold" />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/tvdescription"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/tvnombre"
>         android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
>         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
>         android:layout_weight="1"
>         android:paddingLeft="15dp"
>         android:textColor="#333" />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/tvultvalor"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
>         android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
>         android:layout_weight="1"
>         android:gravity="right"
>         android:paddingLeft="15dp"
>         android:textAlignment="gravity"
>         android:textColor="#333"
>         android:textStyle="bold" />
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

tvnombre is the id of the lef TextView, tvultvalor is the id of the right TextView

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
         android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:paddingStart="16dp"
                android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                tools:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_price"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingStart="16dp"
                android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                tools:text="@string/contact_info" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            tools:text="dummy text" />


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thank you,however,  i made some corrections, and it worked...

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve your layout is creating via Constraint Layout. Similar to what you did, I made a example that can fit for you. Hope this helps you! :-)

```xml
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.11"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvnombre"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#333"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvultvalor"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/tvultvalor"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
        tools:text="dT/dt" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvdescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#333"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvnombre"
        tools:text="N TAG" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvultvalor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textColor="#333"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
        tools:text="100 C" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: good one but there is a disadvantage is here when you add multiple line text in tvnombre the layout will be move in bottom